# compiled llvm trunk, no clang present?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I checked out llvm from the svn repository, configure & make.
After compilation I can not find clang anywhere.
Debug+Asserts/bin has several llvm-x tools, but no clang.

What ame I doing wrong?

Alex

Comment: You should read http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Comment: Yes, I found it in the mean time. The clang site directs to http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#checkout which only checks llvm out. Several pages above #checkout there's a complete list what needs to be checked out